Smoothing out a kink in $\mathbb{R}^n$
I have a continuous map $\gamma: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ which is smooth on $[-1,0]$ and on $[0,1]$. I would like a smooth map $\gamma'$ which agrees with $\gamma$ outside $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ and whose length is approximately the same as $\gamma$. Is there a simple, elementary way to do this?

Let $f:[-1,1]\to[-1,1]$ be a smooth bijection such that $f^{(i)}(0)=0$ for all $i\geq 0$ and for $x\notin (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, we have $f(x)=x$. Then $\gamma\circ f$ traces out exactly the same path, but it slows down enough at the kink to be a smooth map.

Ohhhhh nice! Easier than I expected.

A missing hypothesis is that $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in [-1,1]\setminus [-\varepsilon, +\varepsilon]$ right?

@MatteoDR Right, of course

Another comment: with this technique we can smooth the parametrization $\gamma$ of the curve (obtaining a smooth, but non-regular parametrization). But the curve (as subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$) is unchanged, so we are not ''Smoothing out a kink in  $\mathbb{R}^n$'' as the title suggested. We are simply visiting the kink so slowly that we do not see it (very roughly speaking). To obtain a smooth regular curve that coincides with our curve outside a neighborhood of the kink, one can use convolution with mollfiers techniques/taking a local average/something like this, I think.

@MatteoDR I agree about the question in the title, and it's a fair objection, but the question body only asked about making it a smooth map, so that's what I chose to answer. If we want to actually change the image itself to get a smooth, regular embedding, then you need completely different techniques.

Just to clarify, all I needed was to make the path smooth. I wrote the title that way because I assumed that is how you would have to do it. Actually, for my purposes Arthur's answer is better because the length of the new curve is not just close to, but actually equal to, the length of the original unsmooth curve.

... and I thought about using a mollifier, but getting exact agreement outside of $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ seemed like a bit of a pain.
